# Xcode 10.1 textField secureTextEntry

Tags: swift, xcode

StoryBoard textField checked secureTextEntry, other textField all textFields are asking faceRecognition in iphone X, other lower version of iphones are working fine. Is that iphone x, bug or xcode bug ?

Answer (score 1):

it's not a bug. you are going somewhere wrong.
in your viewDidLoad write this code:

```
MyTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

or you can use attributes inspector -> Text Input Traits -> Secure Text Entry

it working fine on iPhone x.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys i found solution. The problem is not xCode. iPhone x or greater iPhone 
included feature of face recognition users have password auto fill settings. if enabled that settings that page textfield type password, secure textFiled entry and webView input type="password" that all page keyboard not showing language globe button. I think it was problem if username field is required Cyrillic.